# Steps to access basic information from facebook to my website?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am successfull to get "userID" and "access token" but unable to get name and other basic details at my destination page.
How can i get that?
Here is my code.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    FB.init({ appId: '225565837521406', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

   // FB.login({ scope: 'name,email,user_birthday'});


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') 
              {
                var theSession=response.session;
                var theSession = eval('(' + theSession + ')');
                var name=response.name;
                var name=eval('(' + name + ')');
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var email=response.authResponse.email;
//                alert("Name: " +name+ " UserID: " +uid+ " Access Token: " +accessToken);
                document.getElementById("fb-root").innerHTML="Name: " +name+ "<br />UserID: " +uid+ "<br />Access Token: " +accessToken+ "<br />Email: " +email+ "<br />Session: " +theSession;
              } 
              else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
              {
                alert("Not Authorized..");
              } 
              else 
              {
                alert("nothing..");
              }

            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `console.log` of the response - you'll notice the response object contains:

- An '`authResponse`' object, containing an access token, user id, signed request and the expiry for the access token, and
- A status field, telling you the auth status of the user.

Information about the signed request can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Information about Facebook client side auth can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Anyway, none of this gets you information about the user. To do that, you must query the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api). To get basic info about the user, try:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE. The result will be a JSON object containing the users name etc.

HTH